# Configuring "Provisioning Profile" option in Xcode "Code Signing" build settings

Tags: ios, xcode, provisioning-profile, ios-provisioning

I want to be able to have my Xcode project in source control, so other developers can build/test the app. Under "Code Signing Identity" you can specify automatic values like "Developer" / "Distributor" which works well.

However "Provisioning Profile" only lets me see specific profiles. Further, though the documentation says this, my app builds and runs on my test iPad just fine:

> The UUID of a valid provisioning profile. A missing or invalid profile
>   will cause a build error.  [PROVISIONING_PROFILE]

[image]

So how am I supposed to set this up, and what difference will it make?

Answer (score 1):

I found the following Apple URL to be useful in knowing how to setup the Code Signing section of the project settings. [Setting up Xcode to automatically manage your provisioning profiles.](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1814/_index.html)